# How to reduce or disable checkpoint logs in Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am using Flink 1.11.1 and run it on Kubernetes in standalone mode with hdfs for storage and HA. These days, I try to enable the Flink checkpoint feature. But I notice both jobmanger and taskmanagers are logging too many logs relate to the checkpoint which is annoying. Examples are as following:

**Jobmanager**

```
2020-10-08 19:54:23,237 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    - Triggering checkpoint 1 (type=CHECKPOINT) @ 1602186863226 for job fbf26a33a6d5d235085d10e7a10c1cab.
2020-10-08 19:54:42,818 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    - Completed checkpoint 1 for job fbf26a33a6d5d235085d10e7a10c1cab (702534 bytes in 19488 ms).
2020-10-08 19:54:42,825 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    - Triggering checkpoint 2 (type=CHECKPOINT) @ 1602186882820 for job fbf26a33a6d5d235085d10e7a10c1cab.
2020-10-08 19:54:43,384 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    - Completed checkpoint 2 for job fbf26a33a6d5d235085d10e7a10c1cab (729357 bytes in 494 ms).
2020-10-08 19:54:43,392 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    - Triggering checkpoint 3 (type=CHECKPOINT) @ 1602186883388 for job fbf26a33a6d5d235085d10e7a10c1cab.
2020-10-08 19:54:44,295 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    - Completed checkpoint 3 for job fbf26a33a6d5d235085d10e7a10c1cab (736969 bytes in 836 ms).
2020-10-08 19:54:44,302 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    - Triggering checkpoint 4 (type=CHECKPOINT) @ 1602186884298 for job fbf26a33a6d5d235085d10e7a10c1cab.
2020-10-08 19:54:44,794 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    - Completed checkpoint 4 for job fbf26a33a6d5d235085d10e7a10c1cab (748787 bytes in 431 ms).
2020-10-08 19:54:44,800 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    - Triggering checkpoint 5 (type=CHECKPOINT) @ 1602186884796 for job fbf26a33a6d5d235085d10e7a10c1cab.
2020-10-08 19:54:45,198 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    - Completed checkpoint 5 for job fbf26a33a6d5d235085d10e7a10c1cab (755308 bytes in 327 ms).
2020-10-08 19:54:45,703 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    - Triggering checkpoint 6 (type=CHECKPOINT) @ 1602186885698 for job fbf26a33a6d5d235085d10e7a10c1cab.
2020-10-08 19:54:45,897 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    - Completed checkpoint 6 for job fbf26a33a6d5d235085d10e7a10c1cab (757353 bytes in 163 ms).
2020-10-08 19:54:45,903 [INFO] org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator    - Triggering checkpoint 7 (type=CHECKPOINT) @ 1602186885899 for job fbf26a33a6d5d235085d10e7a10c1cab.
```

**Taskmanager**

```
2020-10-08 20:04:02,090 [INFO] org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction - FlinkKafkaProducer 1/2 - checkpoint 571 complete, committing transaction TransactionHolder{handle=KafkaTransactionState [transactionalId=null, producerId=-1, epoch=-1], transactionStartTime=1602187440992} from checkpoint 571
2020-10-08 20:04:03,086 [INFO] org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction - FlinkKafkaProducer 1/2 - checkpoint 572 complete, committing transaction TransactionHolder{handle=KafkaTransactionState [transactionalId=null, producerId=-1, epoch=-1], transactionStartTime=1602187441992} from checkpoint 572
2020-10-08 20:04:03,086 [INFO] org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction - FlinkKafkaProducer 1/2 - checkpoint 572 complete, committing transaction TransactionHolder{handle=KafkaTransactionState [transactionalId=null, producerId=-1, epoch=-1], transactionStartTime=1602187441992} from checkpoint 572
2020-10-08 20:04:04,099 [INFO] org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction - FlinkKafkaProducer 1/2 - checkpoint 573 complete, committing transaction TransactionHolder{handle=KafkaTransactionState [transactionalId=null, producerId=-1, epoch=-1], transactionStartTime=1602187442992} from checkpoint 573
2020-10-08 20:04:04,099 [INFO] org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction - FlinkKafkaProducer 1/2 - checkpoint 573 complete, committing transaction TransactionHolder{handle=KafkaTransactionState [transactionalId=null, producerId=-1, epoch=-1], transactionStartTime=1602187442992} from checkpoint 573
2020-10-08 20:04:05,130 [INFO] org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction - FlinkKafkaProducer 1/2 - checkpoint 574 complete, committing transaction TransactionHolder{handle=KafkaTransactionState [transactionalId=null, producerId=-1, epoch=-1], transactionStartTime=1602187443999} from checkpoint 574
2020-10-08 20:04:05,130 [INFO] org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction - FlinkKafkaProducer 1/2 - checkpoint 574 complete, committing transaction TransactionHolder{handle=KafkaTransactionState [transactionalId=null, producerId=-1, epoch=-1], transactionStartTime=1602187443999} from checkpoint 574
2020-10-08 20:04:06,096 [INFO] org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction - FlinkKafkaProducer 1/2 - checkpoint 575 complete, committing transaction TransactionHolder{handle=KafkaTransactionState [transactionalId=null, producerId=-1, epoch=-1], transactionStartTime=1602187444995} from checkpoint 575
2020-10-08 20:04:06,096 [INFO] org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction - FlinkKafkaProducer 1/2 - checkpoint 575 complete, committing transaction TransactionHolder{handle=KafkaTransactionState [transactionalId=null, producerId=-1, epoch=-1], transactionStartTime=1602187444992} from checkpoint 575
```

Is there any way we can disable or reduce the logs from checkpointing? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to adjust `conf/log4j.properties`?

Comment: I did not try. I am new to it. Not sure how to configure file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simpliest way to disable annoying logs would be to specify the required log level for the target components. In your case if you want to disable logs from `org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint` or more widely from all flink components - `org.apache.flink`, then you can increase the log level for it to `WARN`. To do it, edit the `flink/conf/log4j.properties` file and add the following (or uncomment the existing lines):

```
logger.flink.name = org.apache.flink
logger.flink.level = WARN
```

After the application stop/start the changes will be picked up.